# How to use the Set Builder Notation to express the composite relation $R^n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is what I came up with

$R^n=\{(x,z) ∈ R^n \mid \exists y\,((x,y) ∈ R^n ∧ (y,z) ∈ R^n)\}$

It's just that the $R^n$ bugs me a lot...Can someone explain? I have read the book and look through the web but I don't really get it.

Comment: Is $n\ge0$ or $n\ge1$ ? Serious question, either convention could be in use. What's expected?

Comment: For $R^2$ you must write : $R^2 = \{ (x,z) \mid ∃y[ (x,y) \in R ∧ (y,z) \in R] \}$, but to "generalize" it to $n >2$ is not "formally" correct, because a formula like : $∃y_1 \ldots ∃y_n [ (x,y-1) \in R ∧ \ldots ∧  (y_n,z) \in R]$ is not well-formed.

Comment: It just says that n is a positive integer.